# Hibernate many to many: A collection with cascade all-delete-orphan

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, postgresql

I have two entities, Purchase and Product. They have many to many relationship:

```
Purchase >-------purchaseProduct---------< Product
```

beteween them
I have mapped those entities together. Everything works fine while saving  or deleting  a Purchase. Exceptes when I perform an update, only the parent (purchase will be update) and children (LineCommand) won't be updated(Means delete old children from database and insert the new ones).

Here the DDL for both Purchase and Product and Association: LineCommand:

Purchase:

```
CREATE TABLE purchase
    (
      idpurchase serial NOT NULL,
      code character varying(50),
      date timestamp without time zone,
      totalht double precision,
      tva double precision,
      totalttc double precision,
      CONSTRAINT purchase_pkey PRIMARY KEY (idpurchase)
    )
```

Product:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
  idProduct      serial primary key,
  nameAr         varchar(50),
  nameFr         varchar(50),
  preference       varchar(50),
  qtyStart       double PRECISION,
  qtyInHand      double PRECISION,
  sellPrice      double PRECISION ,
  purchasePrice  double PRECISION,
  taxe           double PRECISION
);
```

LineCommand:

```
CREATE TABLE purchaseProduct (
      idPurchase integer,
      idProduct integer,
      qty double PRECISION, 
      price double  PRECISION,
      primary key(idPurchase,idProduct),
      foreign key(idPurchase) references purchase(idPurchase),
      foreign key(idProduct) references product(idProduct) 
    );
```

The mapping for above entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "purchase")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Purchase {
    private LongProperty idPurchase;
    private StringProperty codePurchase;
    private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> datePurchase;
    private DoubleProperty totalHt;
    private DoubleProperty tva;
    private DoubleProperty totalTTC;

    private Set<LineCommand> lineItems = new HashSet<LineCommand>(0);

    public Purchase() {
        this.idPurchase = new SimpleLongProperty();
        this.codePurchase = new SimpleStringProperty();
        this.datePurchase = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        this.totalHt = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        this.tva = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        this.totalTTC = new SimpleDoubleProperty();


    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "purchase_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "purchase_seq_gen", sequenceName = "purchase_idpurchase_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "idpurchase", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public long getIdPurchase() {
        return idPurchase.get();
    }

    public LongProperty idPurchaseProperty() {
        return idPurchase;
    }

    public void setIdPurchase(long idPurchase) {
        this.idPurchase.set(idPurchase);
    }

    @Column(name = "code")
    public String getCodePurchase() {
        return codePurchase.get();
    }

    public StringProperty codePurchaseProperty() {
        return codePurchase;
    }

    public void setCodePurchase(String codePurchase) {
        this.codePurchase.set(codePurchase);
    }

    @Column(name = "date")
    @Convert(converter = LocalDatePersistanceConverter.class)
    public LocalDate getDatePurchase() {
        return datePurchase.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> datePurchaseProperty() {
        return datePurchase;
    }

    public void setDatePurchase(LocalDate datePurchase) {
        this.datePurchase.set(datePurchase);
    }

    @Column(name = "totalHt")
    public double getTotalHt() {
        return totalHt.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty totalHtProperty() {
        return totalHt;
    }

    public void setTotalHt(double totalHt) {
        this.totalHt.set(totalHt);
    }

    @Column(name = "tva")
    public double getTva() {
        return tva.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty tvaProperty() {
        return tva;
    }

    public void setTva(double tva) {
        this.tva.set(tva);
    }

    @Column(name = "totalTTC")
    public double getTotalTTC() {
        return totalTTC.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty totalTTCProperty() {
        return totalTTC;
    }

    public void setTotalTTC(double totalTTC) {
        this.totalTTC.set(totalTTC);
    }


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "primaryKey.purchase", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    public Set<LineCommand> getLineItems() {
        return this.lineItems;
    }

    public void setLineItems(Set<LineCommand> lineItems) {
        this.lineItems = lineItems;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        } else {

            if (this.idPurchase.getValue() == ((Purchase) obj).getIdPurchase())
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Product :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Product")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Product {
    private LongProperty idProduct;
    private StringProperty nameAr;
    private StringProperty nameFr;
    private StringProperty preference;
    private DoubleProperty qtyStart;
    private DoubleProperty qtyInHand;
    private DoubleProperty sellPrice;
    private DoubleProperty purchasePrice;
    private DoubleProperty taxe;

    private Set<LineCommand> items = new HashSet<LineCommand>();


    public void setIdProduct(long idProduct) {
        this.idProduct.set(idProduct);
    }


    public Product() {
        idProduct = new SimpleLongProperty();
        nameAr = new SimpleStringProperty();
        nameFr = new SimpleStringProperty();
        preference = new SimpleStringProperty();
        qtyStart = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        qtyInHand = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        sellPrice = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        purchasePrice = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        taxe = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "product_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "product_seq_gen", sequenceName = "product_idproduct_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "idproduct", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long getIdProduct() {
        return idProduct.get();
    }

    public LongProperty idProductProperty() {
        return idProduct;
    }

    public void setIdProduct(Long idProduct) {
        this.idProduct.set(idProduct);
    }

    @Column(name = "nameAr")
    public String getNameAr() {
        return nameAr.get();
    }

    public StringProperty nameArProperty() {
        return nameAr;
    }

    public void setNameAr(String nameAr) {
        this.nameAr.set(nameAr);
    }

    @Column(name = "nameFr")
    public String getNameFr() {
        return nameFr.get();
    }

    public StringProperty nameFrProperty() {
        return nameFr;
    }

    public void setNameFr(String nameFr) {
        this.nameFr.set(nameFr);
    }

    @Column(name = "preference")
    public String getPreference() {
        return preference.get();
    }

    public StringProperty preferenceProperty() {
        return preference;
    }

    public void setPreference(String preference) {
        this.preference.set(preference);
    }

    @Column(name = "qtyStart")
    public double getQtyStart() {
        return qtyStart.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty qtyStartProperty() {
        return qtyStart;
    }

    public void setQtyStart(double qtyStart) {
        this.qtyStart.set(qtyStart);
    }

    @Column(name = "qtyInHand")
    public double getQtyInHand() {
        return qtyInHand.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty qtyInHandProperty() {
        return qtyInHand;
    }

    public void setQtyInHand(double qtyInHand) {
        this.qtyInHand.set(qtyInHand);
    }

    @Column(name = "sellPrice")
    public double getSellPrice() {
        return sellPrice.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty sellPriceProperty() {
        return sellPrice;
    }

    public void setSellPrice(double sellPrice) {
        this.sellPrice.set(sellPrice);
    }

    @Column(name = "purchasePrice")
    public double getPurchasePrice() {
        return purchasePrice.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty purchasePriceProperty() {
        return purchasePrice;
    }

    public void setPurchasePrice(double purchasePrice) {
        this.purchasePrice.set(purchasePrice);
    }

    @Column(name = "taxe")
    public double getTaxe() {
        return taxe.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty taxeProperty() {
        return taxe;
    }

    public void setTaxe(double taxe) {
        this.taxe.set(taxe);
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "primaryKey.product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<LineCommand> getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }

    public void setItems(Set<LineCommand> lineItems) {
        this.items = lineItems;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        } else {

            if (this.idProduct.getValue() == ((Product) obj).getIdProduct())

                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

LineCommand:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "purchaseProduct")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.product",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idproduct")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "primaryKey.purchase",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idpurchase"))})

public class LineCommand implements Serializable {


    // Compostie key;
    private LineCommandId primaryKey = new LineCommandId();

    private DoubleProperty sellPrice = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private DoubleProperty qty = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private DoubleProperty subTotal = new SimpleDoubleProperty();


    public LineCommand() {

        this.sellPrice = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        this.qty = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        this.subTotal = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

        NumberBinding subTotalBinding = Bindings.multiply(this.qty, this.sellPrice);
        subTotal.bind(subTotalBinding);

    }

    @EmbeddedId
    public LineCommandId getPrimaryKey() {
        return primaryKey;
    }

    public void setPrimaryKey(LineCommandId primaryKey) {
        this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
    }

    @Transient
    public Product getProduct() {
        return primaryKey.getProduct();
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        primaryKey.setProduct(product);
    }

    @Transient
    public Purchase getPurchase() {
        return primaryKey.getPurchase();
    }

    public void setPurchase(Purchase purchase) {
        primaryKey.setPurchase(purchase);
    }


    @Column(name = "price")
    public double getSellPrice() {
        return sellPrice.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty sellPriceProperty() {
        return sellPrice;
    }

    public void setSellPrice(double sellPrice) {
        this.sellPrice.set(sellPrice);
    }

    @Column(name = "qty")
    public double getQty() {
        return qty.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty qtyProperty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(double qty) {
        this.qty.set(qty);
    }

    @Transient
    public double getSubTotal() {
        return subTotal.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty subTotalProperty() {
        return subTotal;
    }

    public void setSubTotal(double subTotal) {
        this.subTotal.set(subTotal);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            Product product = ((LineCommand) obj).getProduct();
           Purchase purchase = ((LineCommand) obj).getPurchase();

            if (getProduct().equals(product))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }


}
```

Since save and delete methodes works perfectly i put only the code of update methode.

```
 public boolean update(Purchase obj) {
        try {
            if (!session.isOpen())
                session = DatabaseUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            Purchase purchase = session.get(Purchase.class, obj.getIdPurchase());
            purchase.setCodePurchase(obj.getCodePurchase());
            purchase.setDatePurchase(obj.getDatePurchase());
            purchase.setTotalHt(obj.getTotalHt());
            purchase.setTva(obj.getTva());
            purchase.setTotalTTC(obj.getTotalTTC());

            purchase.getLineItems().clear();
            purchase.setLineItems(obj.getLineItems());

            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
            return true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }
```

After executing the above function i get an Exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: model.Purchase.lineItems
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections.processDereferencedCollection(Collections.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections.processUnreachableCollection(Collections.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushCollections(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at dao.PurchaseDAO.update(PurchaseDAO.java:41)
    at controller.purchase.PurchaseController.btnSaveClicked(PurchaseController.java:349)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1767)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8390)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3758)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$431/1622936725.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/673617397.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I hope this is clear to identify my main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a new `lineItems` collection instance on the `Purchase`.

Replace:

```
purchase.setLineItems(obj.getLineItems())
```

with:

```
purchase.getLineItems().addAll(obj.getLineItems())
```

Comment: I get an exception : A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Comment: Yes, then merge the `purchase` as I already pointed out in the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35242080/4754790) of yours.

Comment: Thank's a lot. I'm waiting a long for this to work for me. Plz can you mention a resource, to get a solid understanding on Hibernate framework

Comment: I would suggest you read a book about it (you'll find some good ones using your favorite search engines, recommending books is off-topic for SO). Also, [official documentation](http://hibernate.org/) is also good once you understand basics.